# DelayedJob worker is not loading all my app and I'm getting NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a job running with a DelayedJob worker.
It tries to use a constant from `models/a/myclass.rb`

`my_class.rb` looks like this:

```
module A
  MY_CONST = "my_value".freeze

  class B
  end
end
```

In my job class, I'm trying to use `A::MY_CONST` but getting an error `NameError: uninitialized constant A::MY_CONST`

It works fine on the first iteration of DelayedJob but fails starting from the second iteration.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file `models/some_folder/myclass.rb` it should contain a model called
`SomeFolder::MyClass`. If you want to have a model A, put it in `models/a.rb`

[See more](https://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) in "File lookup rules" (a bit dated, but gives the idea) and in [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html).

Comment: You are right, but that is not the problem. I just had a mistake in my example here. I've just fixed that. As I've mentioned, on the first iteration it's working fine. I'm getting the error only from the second iteration